# Blog posts from a user are not showing to content search web part

Tags: blog, content-search-web-part, post

On SharePoint 2013, there is a content search webpart that is displaying all the blogposts from all sites. There is a particular user that his posts are not showing up in the webpart. All the rest authors have no issues in the webpart. The query:

```
contentclass:STS_ListItem_Posts and  -Title="Welcome to my blog!"
```

It seems that this user has the appropriate permissions. His posts have been approved.
The content of the posts has been crawled and I have executed a full crawl to make sure that the content is being actually crawled. The only thing I haven't tried yet, is index reset.

The permission set of the user:

---

[image]

---

Comment: Check the crawl log in central administration for any errors. I had the similar situation when a couple of blog posts were not crawled because of some strange error. I had to manualy retry crawl for those items to become visible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've re-crawled these items but the posts are still missing.

Comment: Check permissions on the blog library for other users? If its crawled properly, there are misconfigurations with Permissions, thats all.

Comment: The user has full control on the blog list...while other users have just Read permission and their posts are shown to the webpart